# Core Audio : Recording in .wav format doesn't work properly

Tags: core-audio

I use `AudioFileWritePackets()` to write data, and it returns no error during
recording. The data format flag I am using is:

```
if(appDelegate.screenRecording){
    cPacket = 0;inNumPackets = inCompleteAQBuffer->mPacketDescriptionCount;
    if (AudioFileWritePackets(nAudioFile, false, numBytes, mPacketDescs, mPacketIndex, &nPackets, inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioData) == noErr) 
    {
        mPacketIndex += nPackets;   
        NSLog(@"sample result");            
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"ext err");  
    }

}
```

Every time it's calling `Nslog(ext err);`
Please help me solve this.